# Prove that $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/ \langle x+y \rangle \cong \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: polynomials, ring-isomorphism

My direction: Set mapping $\varphi:\mathbb{Q}[x,y] \to \mathbb{Q}$ that $\varphi$ is surjective homomorphic and $\ker{\varphi}=\langle x+y \rangle$. Since Noether Theorem, I have $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/\langle x+y \rangle \cong \mathbb{Q}$.

I have try many mapping $\varphi$ but not working. In my attempt to prove this problem, I have found that $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/\langle x,y \rangle \cong \mathbb{Q}$ by set mapping $\varphi: \mathbb{Q}[x,y]\to \mathbb{Q}, \varphi(f)=f(0,0)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The claim is false as stated. We actually have $\Bbb{Q}[x,y]/\langle x+y\rangle\simeq \Bbb{Q}[x]$. The isomorphism follows from the fact that the kernel of the surjective homomorphism
$$
\phi:\Bbb{Q}[x,y]\to \Bbb{Q}[x], f(x,y)\mapsto f(x,-x)
$$
is the ideal generated by $x+y$.

- $\phi$ is surjective, because $\phi(g(x))=g(x)$ for all polynomials $g(x)$.
- The kernel is generated by $x+y$, because we can view $\Bbb{Q}[x,y]$ as $\Bbb{Q}[x][y]$. That is, the ring of polynomials in $y$ with coefficients coming from the integral domain $R=\Bbb{Q}[x]$. Viewed this way, we see that $\phi$ amounts to evaluating the polynomials at the point $y=-x$. The kernel of an evaluation homomorphism $R[y]\to R$ at the point $y=a$, $a\in R$, is more or less automatically generated by $y-a$. A proof comes from the polynomial divison algorithm. A polynomial $f(y)\in R[y]$ can be written in the form $f(y)=q(y)(y-a)+f(a)$ for some polynomial $q(y)\in R[y]$. Observe that the leading coefficient of $y-a$ is equal to $1$. When $R$ is not a field (as is the case here) we need that assumption for the usual long division of polynomials to work.

Comment: Thanks for showing me the first statement is wrong and the way to prove the correct statement!

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the first answer, the claim is false.

What is true is that $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/\langle x,y\rangle\cong\mathbb{Q}$. You can prove this by considering $\varphi:\mathbb{Q}[x,y]\to\mathbb{Q},\;\varphi(f)=f(0,0) $. To compute $\ker(\varphi)$, note that $x,y\in\ker(\varphi)$, so $\langle x,y\rangle\subset\ker(\varphi)$. On the other hand, if $f\in\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ with $f(0,0)=0$, then $f(x,y)$ is of the form $\sum_{i,j}q_{i,j}x^iy^j$ where $i+j>0$.

Edit: As Ennar points out at the comments: a very smart way to see that $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/\langle x+y\rangle$ cannot be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ is the following: We know that a ring modulo an ideal is isomorphic to a field if and only if the ideal is maximal. But $\langle x+y\rangle\subset \langle x,y\rangle\subset\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ and these inclusions are all strict, hence $\langle x+y\rangle$ is not maximal, thus our quotient cannot be a field, while $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field.

Comment: Thank you, I have prove this problem in my attempt to solve the main problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly are you saying. Ideals don't have to be equal for the quotients to be isomorphic in general. I think you need to be a bit more specific here.

Comment: @Ennar Yes, I don't know why I added the last line. My answer was complementary to the other one, providing an example of a quotient that is actually isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$. I think it is better to delete this line, as it is confusing. Thanks.

Comment: I mean, you could say for example that $\langle x + y\rangle$ is not maximal, since $\langle x + y\rangle \subsetneqq \langle x,y\rangle \subsetneqq \mathbb Q[x,y]$.

Comment: @Ennar Sure. Why don't you post this as an answer? It is a very clever way of showing that $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/<x+y>$ cannot be a field.

Comment: Well, I didn't think we needed a new answer as these two are enough, so I thought to sneak in the idea in your answer since you were almost there.

Comment: @Ennar I have added your idea to my edit!

Comment: @EugeneZhang hi, since I wrote this 4 years ago and have no memory of this kind of math, please feel free to make any edits :)